# Mutation Observer on paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to observe class changes on paragraph and I thought Mutation Observers would be good idea to achieve it. However, I can't get it to work. Everything works fine when I'm observing P from my parent DIV, but it creates too much mess and I'd like to observe only my P.

The code that doesn't work:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("post-title");
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
     console.log(mutation);
    });
});

var config = { attributes: true,
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true, 
    subtree: true,

   };
 
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<div data-editable data-name="meta-title" class="title"><p id="post-title">Tytuł posta</p></div>
```

If I set the ID to DIV instead of P, everything works fine. If the ID is set for P element, mutations are not logged. Any ideas what's wrong with it?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with this code?

Comment: Edited the question. Basically, mutations are not logged when I'm trying to observe P instead of DIV.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are seeing honestly. I just copied the code you pasted and it appears to be working to me. https://jsfiddle.net/6w1v0zgt/

Comment: Well your code works in my project but just for that changeStyle function you've wrote. The thing is, I'm adding and removing P classes by external plugin (Content-Tools, a WYSIWYG editor if that matters), and these changes are not observed. They appear in browser inspector, but are not working with my Mutation Observer.